# Flexbox - how to control height proportional to width?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I control the height of a flexbox so that it stays proportional to the width as the element grows?
I want the height of `.inner` to remain proportional to a given ratio as its width changes.

All examples of flexbox I've seen either holds the height constant when the width changes, or grows enough to contain its contents.

**(haml)**

```
.outer
  .inner
    %img
  .inner
  .inner
```

Perhaps the example will be helped if we include an image within it... or maybe not. just throwing an idea out there.

**(sass)**

```
.outer {
  display: flex;      

  .inner {
    flex: 1 1 auto;

  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know too. I've been experimenting with this JsFiddle without success: http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/3/

Answer (score 5):

There is no method specific to flexbox that would manage this.

There is well known `padding-bottom` trick that would permit this but it requires a pseudo-element (for preference) and an internal absolutely positioned div to hold the content.

[**Reference Web Link**](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)

As you will appreciate, absolute positioning is somewhat inflexible so laying out your content would be the main issue.

Applying this to flexbox:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
.inner:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/* otehr ratios */

.ratio2_1:before {
  padding-top: 50%;
}
.ratio1_2:before {
  padding-top: 200%;
}
.ratio4_3:before {
  padding-top: 75%;
}
.ratio16_9:before {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class='content '>Aspect ratio of 1:1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner ratio2_1">
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 2:1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner ratio16_9">
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 16:9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting some vertical spacing between outer elements that I cannot figure out where it comes from.